# BeautifulSoup is not parsing <td> data properly

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm attempting to parse [this page](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/?start=20171124&end=20171130) using BeatifulSoup4 with Python2.7.5. My code looks like this:

```
url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/CRYPTO/historical-data/?
      start=20171124&end=20171130"
url.replace('CRYPTO', crypto['id'])
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)

data = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html5lib')

trs = soup.find(id="historical-data").findAll('tr')
```

where CRYPTO is replaced by 'bitcoin', etc.

Looking at the variables in PyCharm, everything looks good EXCEPT for the data in the table . Instead of seeing this:

```
<tr class="text-right">
<td class="text-left">Nov 30, 2017</td>
<td>9906.79</td>
<td>10801.00</td>
<td>9202.05</td>
<td>10233.60</td>
<td>8,310,690,000</td>
<td>165,537,000,000</td>
</tr>
```

which is what Google Chrome's Inspect window and curl show me, BeautifulSoup shows me this:

```
<tr class="text-right">
<td class="text-left">Nov 30, 2017</td>
<td>0.009829</td>
<td>0.013792</td>
<td>0.009351</td>
<td>0.013457</td>
<td>152</td>
<td>119,171</td>
</tr>
```

Why are the numbers different?

I have used urllib2 and requests. I have used response.text and response.read(). I have parsed using lxml and html5lib. I have tried different encoding such iso-8859 and ascii. Nothing works.

How do I get the proper numbers to display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to instead do something like this:

```
url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/CRYPTO/historical-data/?
      start=20171124&end=20171130"
response = urllib2.urlopen(url.replace('CRYPTO', crypto['id']))
```

…or to make more explicit what’s happening:

```
url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/CRYPTO/historical-data/?
      start=20171124&end=20171130"
newurl = url.replace('CRYPTO', crypto['id'])
response = urllib2.urlopen(newurl)
```

…because as your code is now, your `url.replace('CRYPTO', crypto['id'])` on its own doesn’t change anything; instead it just creates a new string but never does anything with that new string.

Your code’s not changing the `url` string, because that’s not how [`string.replace(…)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) works — and not how Python strings work.

So what’s happening with your current code is that the `CRYPTO` substring in the URL isn’t being replaced before you call `urllib2.urlopen(…)` on it. Thus the results you get are from this URL:

https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/CRYPTO/historical-data/?start=20171124&end=20171130

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my idiocy. Yeah, I know that's not how strings work. Just one of those things...